# Create name_space package that contains standalone installable sub-packages

Tags: python, namespaces, setuptools, packaging

I am currently trying to group a number of related packages together in a parent package (meta_package). While doing so I also want one of the packages to be installable as a standalone package. To do this I created the following folder structure:

```sh
├── meta_package
│   ├── subpackage1
│   │   ├── module.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── subpackage2
│   │   ├── module.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── subpackage3
│   │   ├── module.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── installable_subpackage
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── requirements.txt
│       ├── setup.py
│       ├── installable_subpackage
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── submodule
│       │       ├── __init__.py
│       │       └── module.py
```

Although the structure above achieves the desired result, both when defining the sub-packages as [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) or normal packages, it introduces an extra `installable_subpackage` directory. As a result to import a Class from the `installable_subpackage` I have to use the following import statement:

```sh
from meta_package.installable_subpackage.installable_subpackage.submodule.module import Class
```

I, however, would like to be able to import the Class using the following (shorter) import statement:

```sh
from meta_package.installable_subpackage.submodule.module import Class
```

### What I already tried

#### Use name_space packages

I tried using [namespace packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847554/install-python-repository-without-parent-directory-structure) for the sub-packages instead of using normal packages. This, however, did not solve the extra folder problem and also introduced a number of [python import traps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847554/install-python-repository-without-parent-directory-structure).

#### Import the redundant folder (module) inside the installable_subpackage.**init**.py file

I also tried importing the `installable_subpackage` submodule inside the `installable_subpackage.__init__.py` file:

```py
import meta_package.installable_subpackage.installable_subpackage
```

This however does not seem to work as the `meta_package.installable_subpackage.submodule` import path does not point to the `meta_package.installable_subpackage.installable_subpackage.submodule` module. I think this is because this method only works with Classes and not modules.

#### Use the setuptools packages and package_dir arguments

Lastly, according [to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847554/install-python-repository-without-parent-directory-structure), I tried to use the `setuptools` `packages` and `package_dir` arguments in the `meta_package` setup.py get rid of the extra folder. To do this I used the following setup.py:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name="meta_package",
    ...
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=["meta_package.*"]),
    package_dir={"meta_package.installable_subpackage": "meta_package/installable_subpackage/installable_subpackage"},
)
```

This, however, does also not seem to get rid of the extra folder.

## Question

Is the packaging structure I am trying to achieve possible? Further, if so, is using it encouraged or advised against?

## System information

- Python version: Python 3.8.5
- Virtual environment: Conda

Comment: When using `package_dir`, you can"t really use `find_namespace_packages`, you have to either write the list manually or modify it before assigning it to `packages`. -- Something like this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63141103/11138259

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks a lot that solved my problem! It was indeed a misunderstanding about how the `find_namespace_packages` method and the `package_dir` argument work. Do you maybe also know if in my use case it is better to use a `namespace` package or a standard package? As in my current understanding namespace packages are used primarily for distributing related packages in different folders while preventing name clashes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819649/namespace-vs-regular-package).

Comment: @sinoroc After reading https://python.developreference.com/article/25478339/The+way+to+make+namespace+packages+in+Python I now think using a namespace package makes sense. I would like to give users the opportunity to only install the small submodule without having to download the whole library.

Comment: Thanks for posting all this. Clarified quite a few things for me. BTW, I was able to get this working without namespace packages, I imported the redundant subpackage using this:
from .installablesubpackage.installablesubpackagemodule import *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [@sinoroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11138259/sinoroc):

> When using package_dir, you can"t really use find_namespace_packages, you have to either write the list manually or modify it before assigning it to packages.

As a result to achieve the desired behaviour I had to modify the packages list before supplying it to the `setuptools.setup` method. This could be done in several ways.

### 1. Add a virtual shortened package to the packages list

We can add extra (shortened) module entries for each of the redundant folders to the `packages` list. This can be done by using the following setup.py file:

**setup.py file**

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

# Retrieve package list
PACKAGES = find_namespace_packages(include=["meta_package*"])+["meta_package.installable_subpackage"]

setup(
    name="meta_package",
    ...
    packages=PACKAGES,
    package_dir={
        "meta_package.installable_subpackage": "meta_package/installable_subpackage/installable_subpackage",
    },
)
```

To do this automatically for a number of sub-packages, you can use the following code:

```py
# Retrieve package list
PACKAGES = find_namespace_packages(include=["meta_package*"])

# Add extra virtual shortened package for each of namespace_pkgs that contain redundant folders
namespace_pkgs = ["installable_subpackage"]
exclusions = r"|".join(
    [r"\." + item + r"\.(?=" + item + r".)" for item in namespace_pkgs]
)
PACKAGE_DIR = {}
for package in PACKAGES:
    sub_tmp = re.sub(exclusions, ".", package)
    if sub_tmp is not package:
        PACKAGE_DIR[sub_tmp] = package.replace(".", "/")
PACKAGES.extend(PACKAGE_DIR.keys())

setup(
    name="meta_package",
    ...
    packages=PACKAGES,
    package_dir=PACKAGE_DIR,
)
```

### 2. Modify package list such that it only contains the shortened package

Alternatively, if you want to replace the long module name with a shorter name fully, you can use the following `setup.py`:

**setup.py file**

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

# Retrieve package list
PACKAGES = find_namespace_packages(include=["meta_package*"])

# Remove redundant folders from the package list
PACKAGES = [re.sub(r"\.installable_subpackage\.(?=installable_subpackage.)", ".", package) for package in PACKAGES]

setup(
    name="meta_package",
    ...
    packages=PACKAGES,
    package_dir={
        "meta_package.installable_subpackage": "meta_package/installable_subpackage/installable_subpackage",
    },
)
```

This can also be done automatically for a number of sub-packages using the following code:

```py
# Remove redundant folder from package list
red_folders = ["installable_subpackage"]
exclusions = r"|".join(
    [r"\." + item + r"\.(?=" + item + r".)" for item in red_folders]
)
PACKAGE_DIR = {}
for index, package in enumerate(PACKAGES):
    sub_tmp = re.sub(exclusions, ".", package)
    if sub_tmp is not package:
        PACKAGES[index] = sub_tmp
```

## IMPORTANT REMARKS

- While using the methods described above, it is important to note that they do not yet work if a package is installed in development mode (see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737431/module-found-in-install-mode-but-not-in-develop-mode-using-setuptools)). It is, therefore, better to use the first method since developers can still use the long module name while users can also use the shorter module name.
- Please remember that the methods described above don't work if there is an `__init__.py` file in your namespace package root folder (see the [setuputils documentation](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages)).

## Update

After I got this answer, I tried to put this logic into a `setup.cfg` file so that it would be [PEP517](https://pypi.org/project/pep517/)/[518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) compatible. While doing this, I ran into some problems. The solution to this can be found on this issue I created on [the setuptools GitHub page](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2467). An example repository can be found [here](https://github.com/rickstaa/stand_alone_sub_package_folder_example).